# JQuery to change the text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery and CSS. The problem I am facing is I cannot change the text of the data, no matter how I tried with the id="sensor1" or "sensor4". I am questioning if I can make a span tag like this
`<li><h2>Temperature 1 </h2> <span id="sensor1">500</span> </li>`

My code is at : https://jsfiddle.net/4rj1jf74/2/

I appriciate if you can help and explain to me about this problem. Thank you !

Comment: Just need to include the jquery library https://jsfiddle.net/4rj1jf74/3/

Comment: and since he didn't explain how, you can do it from the gear icon labeled "Javascript" in the top right corner of the javascript quadrant.

Comment: Thank you sir, it works but i have one more question. I made an html file and embeded all css style and javascript code inside it. But when I open this html file using IE or Firefox or Chrome, it does not run that jQuery code. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear if you are solely working with JSFiddle or if you have seperate code somewhere else, like in Visual Studio and you are only testing a segment of your code in JSFiddle..

But nevertheless, if you are solely using JSFiddle, all you have to do is click on the *JavaScript* gear icon in the top right corner of the space where you write your JS, and select a **jquery** library to include in your fiddle.

The JavaScript gear icon looks like this:

[image]

If you have other code, like in Visual Studio then you need to download and reference [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) in your code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4rj1jf74/6/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#sensor1").click(function() {
    $(this).html(342);
  });
});
```

It will only work if you load jQuery inside your file/project.
I chose "click" as trigger, of course you can change it to fit your needs.